# DataContext.CreateDatabase is creating the database with columns in random order

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-express, datacontext

I am having a c#.Net desktop application in which I use Linq as ORM and SQL server Express as my database. So, when I use dataContext.CreateDatabase() method, 90 % of the times it is creating the columns in the same order as in linq.cs. In that remaining 10%, the order of the few columns is jumbled. (percentages mentioned are approximate. Linq.cs is generated from SqlMetal)

Is there a specific reason why it happens or is there some setting for controlling that..?
I thought of using the order since the number columns is around 30. And there are 15 to 20 tables as such.

**UPDATE**

We are using the database in a hybrid way(i.e., also execute SQL commands directly). That is one reason why i am looking for order of columns.

Comment: No, sorry. The reason you care about order is that you do have bad coding standards. Fields are ALWAYS EVER ONLY to be queried by name. Hybrid is no excuse here. Using order without defiend field order is gross neglect.

Comment: I kind of understand, the mistake i am doing. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In its internals, LINQ-to-SQL uses the SQL language. When it creates tables, if you log your SQL Server, you will see SQL statements, like ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN...

ADD COLUMN does not allow setting a column position. More generally, SQL (the language, weather it's Oracle, MySQL or SQLServer) does not provide tools to control columns position, so the order of the columns is only dependent on the order in which they have been created.

This behavior is intended. You should not rely on column order ever. Most data access frameworks explicitly advice against it and they don't guarantee the constancy of the order of columns you have at any point.

Plus, in your case, you're using LINQ-to-SQL, so unless you are going to use it in an hybrid way (ie also execute SQL commands directly), order will not matter, since you will access columns through corresponding named properties.

So, if indeed you use it in an hybrid way, be sure to always specify column names when you execute SqlCommands. Do not write `INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1,2,3)`, write instead `INSERT INTO MYTABLE(COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (1,2,3)`.

Also, I don't quite understand why you say you are going to use order since there are 30 columns. First, 30 is not high (neither is 20 tables), and second, if they can be called by their position (like ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2, ADDRESS3) generally it means that the database design is flawed. See [1st normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Comment: Well, we do have hybrid way of using. That is where the problem came. May be I shall update in the question.

Comment: I am more curious about the statistics observed there.

Comment: No, you should update your code ;) Referencing field by position? If you are junior: talk to your senior. If you are senior: please work for the competition. This type of (beginner) mistake. Update your code to explicitly name the fields you reference. IN some months you will thank everyone advising you to do so.

Comment: It's ok to use hybrid mode: with LINQ-to-SQL there are things you cannot do, like bulk insert. But as it has been said you should always call columns by their names.

Comment: 30 columns is a really rare case. Even in denormalized DW star schemas. If it is an operational db then, definitely, there is some architectural inconsistencies.